# Can I use alias or const as JSON key to JSON_EXTRACT function

Tags: mysql, json, database

I wounder if thereas way to use const or alias as key to extract JSON data. For example we have json like this in our DB.

```
{
"key1": "value1",
"key2": "value"
}
```

then we can get value1 as this

```
col->>'$.key'
```

or this

```
JSON_EXTRACT(col, '$.key')
```

But what if i need to achiv this by using value that a get in subquery ?

```
@X =: "key1"
//or
SELECT data FROM table AS x
```

I spend like about tree ours alredy but I don't see how to get it work like

```
JSON_EXTRACT(col, @X)
```

All things get just "Invalid JSON path expression"

I was try with CONCAT and different escape symbols, but still same error

Answer (score 1):

You need to concatenate `$.` to the value you extracted.

```
JSON_EXTRACT(col, CONCAT('$.', @X))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mysql> select json_extract('{"key1": "value1","key2": "value"} ','$.key2') AS foo ;
                                                                 ^^^^^^^^
+---------+
| foo     |
+---------+
| "value" |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

With a user-defined variable:

```
mysql> set @X := 'key2' ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select json_extract('{"key1": "value1","key2": "value"} ',CONCAT('$.',@X)) AS foo ;
                                                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
+---------+
| foo     |
+---------+
| "value" |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

or

```
mysql> set @X := '$.key2' ;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select json_extract('{"key1": "value1","key2": "value"} ',@X) AS foo ;
                                                                 ^^  
+---------+
| foo     |
+---------+
| "value" |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

retrieving the key value from a query, as an inline view:

```
mysql> select json_extract('{"key1": "value1","key2": "value"} ',CONCAT('$.',t.bar)) AS foo
    -> from ( select 'key2' AS bar ) t ;
+---------+
| foo     |
+---------+
| "value" |
+---------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

The inline view can be joined to the actual table we're retrieving the json from:

```
 SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(s.jsoncol, CONCAT('$.',k.bar)) AS foo
   FROM mytable s
  CROSS
   JOIN ( SELECT 'key2' AS bar ) k
```